# Actualizar Campos Tablas Relacionadas ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, linq, entity-framework-6

Tengo una base de datos con el siguiente esquema
[![Modelo][1]][1]

En la cual genero la siguiente vista

```
//mi clase
    public class ListarCliente
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int Codigo_Cliente { get; set; }
        public string Dui { get; set; }
        public string Nombre { get; set; }
        public string Apellidos { get; set; }
        public string Operacion { get; set; }
    }

//mi controlador

            List<ListarCliente> clientes;
            using (BancoEntities bd = new BancoEntities())
            {
                clientes = (from cliente in bd.Cliente

                            select new ListarCliente
                            {
                                //Id = cliente.Cod_Cliente,
                                Codigo_Cliente = cliente.Cod_Cliente,
                                Dui = cliente.dui,
                                Nombre = cliente.Nombre,
                                Apellidos = cliente.Apellidos,
                            }).ToList();
            }

            return View(clientes);
        }

//mi vista

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">

        <table class="table">
            <thead class="thead-dark">
                <tr>
                    <th>ID</th>
                    <th>DUI</th>
                    <th>NOMBRE</th>
                    <th>APELLIDO</th>
                    <th>OPERACION</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <!-- Recorro el modelo para imprimir datos -->
            @foreach (var elemento in Model)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>@elemento.Codigo_Cliente</td>
                    <td>@elemento.Dui</td>
                    <td>@elemento.Nombre</td>
                    <td>@elemento.Apellidos</td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="button" class="btn btn-danger" value="Operar" onclick="document.location.href='@Url.Content("~/ListarCliente/Operar/"+elemento.Codigo_Cliente)'"  />

                    </td>
                </tr>
            }

        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

esto genera la siguiente vista(hasta aqui voy bien)

[![vista][2]][2]

**Aquí solicito su ayuda** Lo que tengo que hacer es que al presionar el botón operar me abra otra vista con los siguientes datos(no la puedo hacer)
[![Vista a generar][3]][3]
No se como cargar las cuentas del cliente ni el tipo de transacción en el drowdoplist, ni como actualizar el saldo y el valor(no se como crear esta vista ni hacer el update)

He creado una clase modelo con los valores que necesito pero no me funciona.

```
// clase modelo con los datos que necesito
    public class ModeloCliente
    {

        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int Codigo_Cliente { get; set; }
        public string Numero_Cuenta { get; set; }
        public string TipoTrans { get; set; }
        public decimal Saldo { get; set; }
        public decimal Valor { get; set; }

     }

// controlador


    public ActionResult Listar(int id)
            {
                 List<ModeloCliente> clientes;
                using (BancoEntities bd = new BancoEntities())
                {
                    ModeloCliente cl = new ModeloCliente();


                    clientes = (from cliente in bd.Cliente
                               join cuenta in bd.Cuenta
                               on cliente.Cod_Cliente equals cuenta.Cod_Cliente
                               join transaccion in bd.Transaccion
                               on cuenta.Numero_Cuenta equals transaccion.Numero_Cuenta
                               join tipo in bd.Tipo_Transaccion
                               on transaccion.Id_Tipo_Transaccion equals tipo.Id_Tipo_Transaccion
                                where cliente.Cod_Cliente == id
                                select new ModeloCliente
                               {
                                   Id = cliente.Cod_Cliente,
                                   Codigo_Cliente = cliente.Cod_Cliente,
                                   Numero_Cuenta = cuenta.Numero_Cuenta,
                                   Saldo = cuenta.Saldo,
                                   TipoTrans = tipo.Nombre_Transaccion,

                                   //Operacion = tipo.Nombre_Transaccion

                                }).ToList();

                }

                return View(clientes);

            }

He tratado de hacerlo asi pero no me funciona(ademas que no se como llenar los drowdoplist), no se como actualizar los campos y la vista tampoco se como hacerla espero puedan orientarme de como hacerlo
```

**Ya logre generar la vista gracias a la ayuda**
Pero ahora tengo duda en como actualizar el campo saldo de la tabla **Cuenta**, y tipo de transaccion de la tabla **Transaccion**

```
        BancoEntities bd = new BancoEntities();
        //Metodo para obtener saldo por ajax jquery
        public JsonResult SaldoCuenta(string id_cuenta)
        {
            return Json(bd.Cuenta.First(c => c.Numero_Cuenta == id_cuenta ).Saldo, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
        public ActionResult Operar(int id)
        {

            BancoEntities bd = new BancoEntities();
               // cargar drow tipo trans
            List<Tipo_Transaccion> TipoTrans = new List<Tipo_Transaccion>();
            TipoTrans = bd.Tipo_Transaccion.ToList();
            ViewBag.TipoTrans = new SelectList(TipoTrans, "Id_Tipo_Transaccion", "Nombre_Transaccion");

            //cargar cuentas clientes
            ModeloCliente clien;
            clien = new ModeloCliente();
            {
                clien.Codigo_Cliente = id;
            };

            ViewBag.Numero_Cuenta = new SelectList(bd.Cuenta.ToList(), "Numero_Cuenta", "Numero_Cuenta");


            return View(clien);

        }


@using (Html.BeginForm("Operar", "ListarCliente", FormMethod.Post))
{
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Cuentas del Cliente:</label> @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Numero_Cuenta, null, "seleccione")
                <br />
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Tipo Trans:</label> @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.TipoTrans, null, "seleccione")
                <br />
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Saldo:</label>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Saldo, null, new { disabled = true })<br />
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Valor Transaccion:</label>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Valor)
            </div>

            <input type="submit" value="guardar" class="btn btn-primary"  />
        </div>
    </div>


}

<script>
      //obtengo numero cuenta drowdowlist y cargo saldo
    $("#Numero_Cuenta").change(function () {
        console.log("Exito");
        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("SaldoCuenta","ListarCliente")',
            data: { id_cuenta: $(this).val() },
            success: function (a) {
                $("#Saldo").val(a);
            }
        });
    });

</script>
Ahora en mi controlador como hago la actualizacion de solo los campos mencionados anteriormente

 [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Detalle(ModeloCliente model)
        {

            try
            {
                if (ModelState.IsValid)
                {
                    using(BancoEntities bd = new BancoEntities())
                    {
                        var oCuenta = bd.Cuenta.Find(model.Numero_Cuenta);
                        oCuenta.Saldo = model.Saldo;
                    }

                }

            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                throw new Exception(e.Message);
            }

            return View();
        }
```

Ahora en mi controlador como hago la actualizacion de solo los campos mencionados anteriormente

```
 [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Detalle(ModeloCliente model)
        {

            try
            {
                if (ModelState.IsValid)
                {
                    using(BancoEntities bd = new BancoEntities())
                    {
                        var oCuenta = bd.Cuenta.Find(model.Numero_Cuenta);
                        oCuenta.Saldo = model.Saldo;
                    }

                }

            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                throw new Exception(e.Message);
            }

            return View();
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

1. En la nueva vista asegurate de tener el Id del cliente para poder buscar sus cuentas.
2. Para el DropDown de las cuentas puedes hacer esto en el controlador :

   `var cuentas = db.Cuentas.where(c => c.Cod_Cliente == idcliente);
    //En la linea de arriba la consulta debe devolver las cuentas del cliente elegido, es un código de ejemplo`

   `// reemplaza Id por el nombre del campo que sirve como Id en la tabla cuenta
   ViewBag.Numero_Cuenta = new SelectList(cuentas,"Id","Numero_Cuenta")`
3. En la vista, usando ModeloCliente como modelo de vista creamos el dropdown así:
   `@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Numero_Cuenta,null,"seleccione")` el DropDownList buscará sus datos en el ViewBag que creamos en el controlador

   4.Para el tipo de transacción haz lo mismo que para  las cuentas, solamente omite el filtrado por id cliente.
4. Para saber el saldo de la cuenta debes crear un evento en el dropdown de las cuentas y cuando cambie el valor seleccionado hacer una petición ajax al controlador ( debes crear el metodo en el controlador que te regrese el saldo de la cuenta a partir del Id de esa cuenta)

[Repositorio con proyecto de ejemplo](https://bitbucket.org/crrlos/test/src/master/)

Comment: Gracias por tu orientación.
Cómo obtengo el ID del cliente en la vista? En el botón operar hago esto input type="button" class="btn btn-danger" value="Operar" onclick="document.location.href='@Url.Content("~/ListarCliente/Operar/"+elemento.Codigo_Cliente)'" /> También no se como actualizar el saldo y valor como iría el código en el controlador.

Comment: Te dejo este proyecto de ejemplo, tiene todo lo que necesitas,estudialo y me consultas si tienes dudas https://bitbucket.org/crrlos/test/src/master/

Comment: Primeramente gracias por tomarte le tiempo de responderme.

Comment: @crrlos Si tengo una duda para implementarlo en mi codigo me aparece el siguiente erro System.InvalidOperationException: 'The operation cannot be completed because the DbContext has been disposed.'        dejare el codigo en la pregunta

Comment: No pongas el bancoentities en el using , solo crea la  instancia y úsala así.

Comment: @crrlos perfecto  muchas gracias ya logre cargar los drowdowlist y colocar el saldo segun cuenta seleccionada(ya tengo la vista creada) lo que tengo dudas ahora es como actualizar el campo saldo de la tabla cuenta, y el campo id transaccion de la tabla transaccion. Dejo codigo en la pregunta para que veas como lo he realizado

Comment: Antes de cerrar el using(){} coloca instrucción bd.SaveChanges(); En este momento debería actualizarte el saldo de la cuenta. Lo del id  de la transacción depende como lo estés manejando pero todo lo que hagas que tenga que ver con manipular datos colocalo antes de  bd.SaveChanges();